# Metrics Tracking for MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is there any plug in or extension we can use for integrating metrics tracking for MS Teams.
I tried Aptelligent for metrics but it is not supported by MS teams.

Answer (score 1):

Everything we have is published in [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/microsoft-teams-user-activity-reports?view=graph-rest-1.0) and/or the Modern Portal. There are no client-side plugins or extensions currently.